# How to add manual tasks in an Apache Airflow Dag

Tags: airflow

I'm using Apache Airflow to manage the data processing pipeline. In the middle of the pipeline, some data need to be reviewed before the next-step processing. e.g.

`... -> task1 -> human review -> task2 -> ...`

where task1 and task2 are data processing task. When task1 finished, the generated data by task1 needs to be reviewed by human. After the reviewer approved the data, task2 could be launched.
Human review tasks may take a very long time(e.g. several weeks).

I'm thinking to use an external database to store the human review result. And use a [Sensor](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html#basesensoroperator) to poke the review result by a time interval. But it will occupy an Airflow worker until the review is done.

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea seems good to me. You can create a dedicated DAG to check the progress of your approval process with a sensor. If you use a low timeout on your sensor and an appropriate schedule on this DAG, say every 6 hours. Adapt it to how often these tasks are approved and how soon you need to perform the downstream tasks.

Answer (score 5):

Piggy-packing off of [Freedom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57621812/1812739) and [Robert Elliot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48580341/how-to-add-manual-tasks-in-an-apache-airflow-dag/57594459#57594459), here is a full working example that gives the user two weeks to review the results of the first task before failing permanently:

```py
from datetime import timedelta

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow import AirflowException
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

from my_tasks import first_task_callable, second_task_callable


TIMEOUT = timedelta(days=14)


def task_to_fail():
    raise AirflowException("Please change this step to success to continue")


dag = DAG(dag_id="my_dag")

first_task = PythonOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="first_task",
    python_callable=first_task_callable
)

manual_sign_off = PythonOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="manual_sign_off",
    python_callable=task_to_fail,
    retries=1,
    max_retry_delay=TIMEOUT
)

second_task = PythonOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="second_task",
    python_callable=second_task_callable
)

first_task >> manual_sign_off >> second_task
```

Comment: Why are you using `max_retry_delay` instead of `retry_delay`? `retry_delay` seems more appropriate in this case I would say.

Comment: Till now, other suggestions for this?

Answer (score 3):

A colleague suggested having a task that always fails, so the manual step is simply to mark it as a success. I implemented it as so:

```py
def always_fail():
    raise AirflowException('Please change this step to success to continue')


manual_sign_off = PythonOperator(
    task_id='manual_sign_off',
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=always_fail
)

start >> manual_sign_off >> end
```

Answer (score 0):

Before 1.10, I used the retry feature of the operator to implement the `ManualSignOffTask`. The operator has set retries and retry_delay. So the task will be rescheduled after it fails. When the task is scheduled, it will check the database to see if the sign-off is done:
If the sign-off has not been done yet, the task fails and release the worker and wait for next schedule.
If the sign-off has been done, the task success, and the dag run proceeds.

After 1.10, a new TI state `UP_FOR_RESCHEDULE` is introduced and the Sensor natively supports long running tasks.